# Angular Material Md-Input-Container interferes with Routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-routing

I'm new to stack so please bear with my formatting.

I set up a simple routing program referencing [Angular's routing guide.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)
The initial display page redirects to the login page, with URL ://
localhost:4200/ instead of expected ://localhost:4200/login .

I have the line `<base href="./">` in my index.html, so my program should route properly.My appcomponent template consists only of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
 I have `import { Router } from '@angular/router';` in each of my components and `import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';` in my bootstrapped Appmodule.

My problem is that I cannot route from my login screen to any other screen using routerLink in some button or a direct `<a>` tag. If I manually change the URL it acts appropriately, and routing other files between each other works as expected. I found that, upon removing all `<md-input-container>` tags used in my login.component.html, my login display routes properly and the base URL correctly defaults to ://localhost:4200/login.

Is this a bug? I'm not sure why md-input-container would affect routing, and I still find it hard to believe the original error. I inserted an input enveloped by md-input-container in other files that had been routing correctly, and they starting misbehaving the same way. Of course I want to use md-input-container for formatting and styling but it interferes with what I intend to have my program do. 
My login.component.ts is shown:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginFailed: boolean;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loginFailed = false;
    }
    LoginAttempt = function () {          
        this.router.navigate('/emp.vision');
    }
    LoginError = function () {
        this.loginFailed = true;
        this.loginErrorMessage = "Invalid username/password";
    }   
}`
```

And my login.component.HTML :

```html
<md-card class="login-card">
    <md-card-content>
                <img md-card-image src="assets/Img/loginpageIcon.png">
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; width:35%">
                <p></p>

                <b>Employee #:</b>
                <md-input-container>
                    <input mdInput type="text" ng-model="" />
                </md-input-container>

                <b>Password:</b>
                <md-input-container>
                    <input mdInput type="password" ng-model=""/>
                </md-input-container>

                <p></p>
              <a routerLink="/man-vision" routerLinkActive="active">manager page</a>

                <button  md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="LoginAttempt()">
                    <font color="white">Login</font>
                </button>
                
                <button md-raised-button color="accent" (click)="LoginError()">
                    <font color="white"> Cancel </font>
                </button>

    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

My routing module:

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
//import { NewLoginComponent } from './newlogin.component';
import { EmpVisionComponent } from './emp.vision.component';
import { ManVisionComponent } from './man.vision.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './error.component';



const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',            //Login Screen
        component: LoginComponent
    },
  /*{
        path: 'newlogin',
        component: NewLoginComponent
    },*/
    {
        path: 'emp-vision',           //Employee Screen
        component: EmpVisionComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'man-vision',          //Manager Screen
        component: ManVisionComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',                 //Default Route
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    { 
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent     //Default Screen
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: false })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers:[]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Comment: Not sure if you solved this, but it looks like you're trying to route to `emp.vision` in your controller not `emp-vision` that's in your routes.

Comment: That's a valid point, but fixing it did not solve the problem. It seems to entirely depend on md-input-container.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed when material became a peer dependency of /@angular/cdk.